# stuck with root user, can not return to normal user

Tags: root

Although previously exited root user account via ctrl-d/ or exit, but new terminal still entered as root, how do I switch back to normal user upon new entry to terminal?

Comment: `su - your_username`

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch, I just forgot my user name, was using the root for so long, lucky haven't break the system yet XD

Comment: Well, you can search it is still configured in system by looking at file that hold's informations regarding existing accounts : 'cat /etc/passwd' and try searching your username. Also, you can create another account.

Comment: You never should log in as root user (use `sudo`instead, if you need root privileges). `getent passwd` will give you a list of all users in the system; 'normal' users begin at UID 1000. `getent group sudo` will show you which users are enabled to run `sudo`). And if you forgot the password of your 'normal' user, you may set it (as root) through `passwd <username>`.

Comment: That's true, I neede to enable ssh for rsync my pi, at the time trying to get the right config to work for the ssh was asking too many times of password so I stayed as root. But it was definitely a dangerous move.